# error while running apache beam word count example on standalone flink cluster (Apache flink 1.9.0)

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam-io, apache-beam

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project word-count-beam: An exception occured while executing the Java class. Class org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$StandardPTransforms$Primitives does not implement the requested interface org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum

```
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.BeamUrns.getUrn (BeamUrns.java:27)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.<clinit> (PTransformTranslation.java:135)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PTransformMatchers$6.matches (PTransformMatchers.java:263)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$2.enterCompositeTransform (Pipeline.java:270)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit (TransformHierarchy.java:653)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit (TransformHierarchy.java:657)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600 (TransformHierarchy.java:317)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit (TransformHierarchy.java:251)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically (Pipeline.java:460)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replace (Pipeline.java:260)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replaceAll (Pipeline.java:210)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.translate (FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.java:114)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner.run (FlinkRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:315)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:301)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.runWordCount (WordCount.java:208)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.main (WordCount.java:250)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-runners-flink-1.9</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Got this one, this is due to dependency version mismatch. Actually the version of my link cluster and dependency version were not compatible.